# Calling MVC 5 WEB API with ajax causes error when I include authorizationheader. OPTIONS call to the server is not allowed

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm having trouble calling my web api with authentication. It works fine if I leave it out and call methods that don't need authentication.

You guys see anything off in this code?

Here is my ajax call to the server.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
function GetAllPlayers() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: webServiceUrl + "/api/Player/GetAllPlayers",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + $.cookie("fanaTok")); },
    success: function (result) {
        //TODO handle success
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //TODO Handle error
    }
});
}
```

And here is my web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Calling to localhost

The error message:

OPTIONS /api/Player/GetAllPlayers 405 (Method Not Allowed)

OPTIONS/api/Player/GetAllPlayers Invalid HTTP status code 405

XMLHttpRequest cannot load/api/Player/GetAllPlayers. Invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: Can you include the header class of the web.api and Register method from application_start?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you'r talking about. It's not only one method i have to call with authentication, it's almost all methods except the login function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong.

The web api did not accept OPTIONS call to the server to verify if the custom authentication header was allowed.

I came across an article where this OPTIONS problem is fixed

http://www.jefclaes.be/2012/09/supporting-options-verb-in-aspnet-web.html

It took me a very long time to figure this out, I hope this helps.